# Experiments are monads (I think), but are they comonads too?

Tags: measurements, foundations, category-theory

Quantum theory is equally an epistemic (ie about information) and ontic theory (see "reality of the wavefunction" on Google Scholar). My question is about a theory that aligns with this, ie, the structure of experimentation is supported by an evolutionary step in an evolving spacetime.

[I have tried to give a description](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322766016_Experiments_and_Theories_A_Fundamental_Model) of experiments as monads and [applied it to a though experiment by Lucien Hardy](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/327977298_A_Concise_Depiction_of_Cosmological_Experiments).  The basic idea is that spacetimes are equivalent to interval domains, and therefore an evolutionary step in a universe is a domain map which is also a functor.  The local environment (where all experiments are done) is a fixed category, and therefore the local map is an endomap and thus an endofunctor.  The product $F \cdot F \rightarrow F$ handles the idea that repeated experiments go towards one monolith of data.

It seems quite natural to expect that we should also have a coproduct, $F \rightarrow F \cdot F$, implying that the endofunctor is also a comonad.  The reason this seems very plausible to me is that we need copying.  Experiments can be copied, so that other people can reproduce your results, and data can be copied in the normal sense.  I just have not figured out what the exact mechanism should be for the copying natural transformation.  What should that copying natural transformation be?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about information theory and not mainstream physics.

Comment: Information theory is considered non-mainstream?

Comment: Quantum theory is equally an epistemic (ie about information) and ontic theory (see "reality of the wavefunction" on Google Scholar).  My question is about a theory that aligns with this, ie, the structure of experimentation is supported by an evolutionary step in an evolving spacetime.

Comment: How would your "copying" of data comply with the "no-cloning theorem"?

Comment: In Heunen's paper he is talking about quantum measurements.  These are internal comonoids in Hilb, which we take as bases.  They are classical and can be copied.

Comment: Consider the composition of "measure the position of object A" followed by "measure the momentum of object A". Every state in the Hilbert subspace for that object as an initial state is mapped into every state as a possible final state.  If you are considering arbitrary experiments, it sounds like you are abstracting to the point of not saying anything at all.

Comment: This reads like word salad to me. If you're expecting answers from people already immersed in your formalism then I guess that'd be OK, but it doesn't sound like that's the case, so: in the interest of getting a good answer, I would suggest adding a good deal more background to this post.

Comment: Can you give a reference for viewing experiments as monads that is *not* the paper you wrote yourself? That is, can you give any mainstream reference for what you are talking about in this question, or is this entirely your own theory? Note that we do not evaluate personal theories here, nor do we do research here - the non-mainstream policy applies regardless of the actual merit of the personal theory.

Comment: (And, regarding ACuriousMind's comments, take into account the considerations in [Is Physics SE an appropriate location for peer review?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7516/is-physics-se-an-appropriate-location-for-peer-review).)

Comment: Related meta post: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10200/2451

Comment: S. Majid talked about duality between experiment and theory. I think there is some of that in his Hopf algebra book. I can't remember if he describes experiment as a monad, I think not, but he does give some sort of example for sure, I believe from QM. It isn't quite what you're talking about if I remember, but there might be links.